# PHP Photo to PDF

Tags: php, pdf

I am a beginner fumbling wiht PHP at this moment. Here is what I need to build.

1. Let users upload photos from my website. Multiple photos of course, probably 10-20 or more in one shot.
2. Store those photos in my web server
3. Stitch those photos into a PDF document and let the user download the PDF file in his computer.

I am done up to step 2. How do I stitch all the photos into a PDF document? So for example, if the user has uploaded 6 photos, I want him to download a 6 page PDF with each photo on every page.

I have been scratching my head on this for days and searching the internet, couldn't find anything. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use TCPDF for generating PDF. Please go through this link for more details. It is easy to implement with PHP

http://www.tcpdf.org/

http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_009.phps